# Why is Elrindir at The Drunken Huntsman mad at me?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Elrindir used to be friendly, greeting me with lines like "Ah my Khajiit friend what are you hunting?" or something like that.

Now I'm getting a more hostile "What do youuu want you rat scum?" from him.

What did I do, can I reconcile with him?

Comment: Did you, by any chance, complete a particular... Dark Brotherhood contract in Whiterun?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you do the Dark Brotherhood contract to kill Anoriath?

Anoriath is Elrindir's brother, if you do it stealthily he'll deal with you normally but if he knows you did it, he'll be hostile to you.

Comment: That's it, I did it and ran.

Comment: @Mike That's it then :)

Comment: +1 since I am not sure @Mike is going to mark this as the answer!

Comment: Done, it gave me a warning yesterday, I had to wait 10 minutes, and then I forgot to come back